# How can I print in one column the SUM of two columns

Tags: excel

[image: Worksheet]

I have the above excel and I want B column always print the SUM of C and D column. Is this possible instead of go every cell in b and write the function manually?

Comment: Type in B2 = sum(C2:D2), and drag it down?

Comment: Thank you very much. I am not familiar with excel. If you want write it as answer in order to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simply: Type in B2

```
=sum(C2:D2)
```

and drag it down.